# PHP Mime Type for apk files

Tags: php, .htaccess

Why PHP method `$mime = mime_content_type($filename);` gives `mime-type = application/zip` for apk files?? I've defined apk mimetype in htaccess

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive     apk
    AddType application/apk                             apk
    AddType application/java-archive                    jar
</Ifmodule>

<FilesMatch \.apk$>
    SetHandler application/vnd.android.package-archive
</FilesMatch>
```

**I've tried all the solutions provided below but still none of them solved the problem. Need help regarding this.**

Comment: Please add below line to your htaccess

AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive apk

i mean without any table or any if condition.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: tried but still its giving application/zip

Comment: Is `mime_magic_module` enabled?

Comment: Under "Loaded Modules: mod_mime_magic and mod_mime_mod" is showing

Comment: Any other suggestions please????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `mime_content_type` is [not affected](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/fileinfo/fileinfo.c#L620) by `.htaccess`. However, the documentation [specifies](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) that you can set `magic.mime` file:

> string mime_content_type ( string $filename )
>
> Returns the MIME content
>   type for a file as determined by using information from the `magic.mime`
>   file.

There is also [finfo_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) (PECL) function that has `$magic_file` as a parameter.

Comment: in httpd.conf, **mime_module** is enabled and the mime mapping file _/etc/mime.types_ contains the apk mime type, so if i remove the mime type from _htaccess_, it should get the correct apk mime type from that file, but it is not getting from that file. Why is it so? and on adding it in htaccess also doesn't do anything.

Comment: Also, when i run this command through php `$command = "file -b --mime-type -m /etc/magic {$filename}";` i get mime type as **application/octet-stream**

Comment: This talks a bit about updating /etc/magic: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_2.1.2/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.productization.iisinfsv.install.doc/topics/wsisinst_config_pe_etcmagic.html?lang=en However, I'm not sure if /etc/mime.types and /etc/magic is the same. I don't think so.

Comment: I've tried this `$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME, "/etc/magic");` and the output of this is also **application/octet-stream; charset=binary**

Comment: The database `/etc/magic` must contain an error then. I don't see any other explanation.

Comment: I've gone through the magic file nowhere it contains the magic data for **application/vnd.android.package-archive**. How can i get the correct data set for this mime type which i can add to magic file

Comment: This is as far as I got with searching for the /etc/magic file format: http://askubuntu.com/questions/427509/file-mime-type-vs-mimetype-for-php-files ... However, it is getting more and more complicated. I would solve your problem by simply checking last 4 characters of file name (if it is equal to `.apk`). In the end, that's what you want to achieve anyway.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the help. That's the last solution am going to use.